# Spring Data JPA - Get All Unique Values in Column

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a project using Spring Data JPA that consumes data from a table full of addresses. One of the columns of this table is the city. I would like to get a distinct list of cities that are in the table i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT city FROM address`.

Is there a way to do this using Spring Data JPA?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `@Query` annotation as:

```java
public interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT a.city FROM Address a")
    List<String> findDistinctCity();
}
```

Then, a call to `addressRepository.findDistinctCity()` would return the distinct city names.

A sample application is available on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/42619129) for review. Run integration test as `mvn clean test` to verify the approach.

Comment: I tried it and the following error was returned upon calling the method: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!`. Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you checked the sample app? If the problem persists, please post the full code to reproduce the error.

Comment: I did some further test and it seems like the issue exists in the Spring Data Rest part, when calling directly from code it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Spring Data REST repository methods can only return entities by default. However, you can write a projection for returning specific attribute values like in your example. The official documentation covers these cases in good detail.

Comment: also worth mentioning that the Query here should contain the mapped names and not the database names. So, for example if the database table name is `city_name` then the query would contain the mapped name i.e. `CityName` same goes for the column names as well

Comment: You must create a wrapper class with @Entity and the String on it.

Answer (score 2):

Manish's comment should probably be bumped up to an answer (which i'll try to capture here since it ultimately solved my problem...although projections didn't seem to work with `select distinct`).  The selected answer works in spring-data-jpa, but fails in spring-data-rest.  One possible workaround for the spring-data-rest scenario is to create a separate `@RestController` for the `select distinct` results

```
@RestController
public class AddressRepoAdditionals {
     @Autowired
     private AddressRepository repo;

     @RequestMapping("/additional/address/distictCities")
     public List<String> findDistinctCity() {
          return repo.findDistinctCity();
     }
 }
```

perhaps there's a similar but more elegant variation based on @RepositoryRestController

Comment: This is really lame of spring-data-rest! but this works even for List<Object[]> return values. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use native query.

`@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name", nativeQuery = true)`
`List<Type> findDistinctColumnValues();`